# react native mobx value is not primitive

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I build react native app and I'm using mobx.
into the store I have array called tools, when i try to assign values into array I get the array

> Encountered an uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[Reaction@1] Error: [serializr] this value is not primitive: 14

```
 class Task {
@persist @observable id = ''
@persist @observable title = ''
@persist @observable description = ''
@persist @observable tools = []

constructor(id,title,description,tools){
    console.log('new task')
    console.log(id,title,description,tools)
    this.id = id
    // this.title = title
    this.description = description
    this.tools = tools;

}
```

TasksStore - here I create new object of Task.

```
    import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'
import { persist } from 'mobx-persist'
import Task from '../Task/Task'
class TasksStore {

    @persist('list',Task) @observable tasks = []
    @observable storeHydrated = false;


    @action done(){
        this.storeHydrated = true

    }

    @action addNewTask(task){
        this.tasks.push(new Task(0,task.title,task.description,task.tools))
        console.log('tasks is',this.tasks)
    }






}


const taskStore = new TasksStore();
export default taskStore;
```

when I remove

```
    @persist @observable tools = []
```

the app works fine.

Comment: What is the sample value of the `task.tools` that you're providing?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I believe it's related with `mobx-persist`. Could you post your `hydrate(..)` code and `Task` class?

Answer (score 4):

```
@persist('list') @observable tools = []
```

try to set type of tools.
It will work

Comment: this is the correct answer; in other words if your are inside your decorator you need to declare the prop as `tools: [persist('list'), observable]`. `persist` is not enough. You need `persist('list')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.The solution is to make the Task class serializable like this:

```
class Task {
 @serializable @observable id = ''
 @serializable @observable title = ''
 @serializable @observable description = ''
 @serializable(list(primitive()))   @observable tools = []

constructor(id,title,description,tools){
  console.log('new task')
  console.log(id,title,description,tools)
  this.id = id
  // this.title = title
  this.description = description
  this.tools = tools;  
}
```

And persist your now serializable Task in your store:

```
class Store{
  @persist('object', Task)
  @observable
  public Task= new Task()
}
```